# Can 302 redirect on WordPress homepage affect SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, 302-redirect

I manage a website. In order to lead the visitor to the latest post when entering the website, I set a 302 redirect from the homepage URL to the latest post URL. There's 1 to 2 posts a month so the redirection is made manually each time a new post gets published.

Despite the website registration on Google it doesn't get indexed at all. After searching for some solution on blogs and forums I understood this issue might be related to the 302 redirection. It's the first time I use redirections on a website, can someone help me?

Comment: "it doesn't get indexed at all." - the page you are redirecting to doesn't get indexed? How long have these pages been public? Are other pages indexed? "website registration on google" - what do you mean by "registration"? Have you submitted an updated sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.

There are many situations where a 302 is appropriate. It should consider How often have you temporarily moved a page. SEO specialists mostly don’t use 302 redirects when fixing the on-site qualities of a website. Instead, a 302 redirect is often used when they want to test a new page for client feedback but they don’t want to damage or change the old page’s rankings and history.

Comment: _Why_ will it affect SEO in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

The 302 redirect may be confusing Google.  It should be possible to get your site indexed even with a occasionally changing 302 redirect for a home page.  To do so:

- Make sure each of your posts links to the other posts.   WordPress usually including "next/previous article" links as well as links to tags and categories.   The idea is that once Googlebot finds one page, it should be able to get to all the rest.
- Submit an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) to Google.  XML sitemaps help when a site is hard for Googlebot to crawl.   There are WordPress plugins that can do this for you.
- Try crawling your site yourself.   You often don't know why Google isn't crawling your site until you do this to reveal problems.   There are plenty of crawlers out there.  I tend to use `wget` in recursive mode on the command line.
- Make sure some other sites link to some of your articles.   If you have another site, or friends that you ask for a link, those are great ways to get Google to notice your site.  It only takes a couple inbound links for Google to realize that your site has enough value to index.